# Confused with Chemical Formula Function Design : If statement won't print "Hi" when it's supposed to

Tags: python, list, loops, csv, dictionary

```
def compound_properties(csv_name, compound_formula):
compDict = molform(compound_formula)

compK = compDict.keys()
sList = []
ele = ''
with open("atoms.csv", "r") as atomsF:
elemData = list([row for row in csv.reader(atomsF)])
for i in compK:
  ele = str(i)
  for j in elemData: 
    sList = j
    if ele in sList:
      print('hi')
```

How do I check if this element is within this list I generated with a for loop? The If statement I have doesn't print "hi" like it is supposed to. How do I fix this??

This function takes two parameters: the csv filename and the formula of the compound.

It should call the molform() function to get the composition of the molecule and
  get the required property from the csv file. The csv file will have all the
  properties required.

This function is required to return a tuple of three properties:
  1. The NAME of the atom with the lowest boiling point. 
      For example, if it's oxygen, return 'Oxygen', not 'O'

Comment: Instead of `sList = j` , can you try `sList.append(j)`. And try running the code again.

Comment: If you supply us with a little more info (how `compDict` looks, what else the function should return, where `csv_name` comes into play etc.) we could help you a little better.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can shorten your code quite a bit by removeing unnecessary declarations.

**Edit:** I'm guessing you want to open `csv_name`, not `"atoms.csv"`?

With everything obsolete removed, it looks like this (take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for more info on `csv.reader`):

```
def compound_properties(csv_name, compound_formula):
    compDict = molform(compound_formula)

    with open(csv_name, "r") as atomsF:
        elemData = csv.reader(atomsF) # csv.reader already returns a list of rows

    for i in compDict:  # for loop automaticaly iterates over dict keys
        for j in elemData:
            if str(i) in j:  # no need to assign i or j to additional variables
                print('hi')
```

Without any real example data, I can't say more about this right now then that the problem is not within this for loop. With test data, it works perfectly:

```
elem_data = [['this', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'row'], ['this', 'is', 'the', 'bar', 'row'], ['this', 'is', 'all', 'a', 'big', 'foo']]

compDict = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'baz': 3}

for i in compDict:
    for j in elemData:
        if str(i) in j:
            print('{} was found in line {}'.format(i, elemData.index(j) + 1))
```

Output:

```
foo was found in line 3
bar was found in line 2
```

Comment: Beware, never iterate a file (or a `csv.reader') inside a loop! You will reach the end of file after first iteration and the following ones will process an empty file... You must use the opposite order: `for j in elemData: for i in compDict: ...`